# I am not seeing the images, style from another system wamp localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp

I have set up local host with wamp server and installed wordpress. I am able to see my website properly on my computer, but when I am accessing it from another system all files break dowm, images are not seeing only text are seeing on remote system. How I resolve this proble?

Comment: What have you setup in Apache, vhost or alias? How are you accessing your WordPress install from other computer?

Comment: I have setup alias. i am able to access my site by typing in browser: localhost/testwebsite, but when accessing it from another system by typing my ip/testwebsite ot mycomputername/testwebsite, all files looks break, only text is seeing. I installed wampserver 2.5